# How To Restart New Blockchain Sync?

Tags: blockchain, daemon

For some reason today, the Monero wallet stopped connecting to the daemon. The best reason for the error I could find is this: Attempt to get block from height 1396361 failed -- block not in db

So I tried to download a fresh version of the GUI, reboot computer, upload blockchain manually, and whatever else I could find to troubleshoot or fix. No luck.

I just want to start fresh. I have my key, so would like to start over and restore my wallet. But I tried deleting everything and starting over, but daemon will still not run.

I'm on Mac OS X Sierra. Any advice?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, this looks like a corrupt blockchain database.

With 0.11.0.0, monerod has a `--db-salvage` option which might be able to recover your database. Exit monerod, and run it again with that option appended, eg: `./monerod --db-salvage`.

Otherwise, the only fix for tis is to exit monerod, delete the blockchain (~/.bitmonero/lmdb/data.mdb) and start monerod again. It will then sync the blockchain again. Nothing needs to be done with the wallet, the GUI, etc. Just the blockchain.

Comment: Thank you! How do I append monerod? I can open monerod and view it, but it doesn't have the option to edit. I can open a terminal...not sure if that's the route to go. Curious so I can maybe fix this faster than resyncing entire blockchain.

That took about 4 days last time.

If that doesn't work out, I'll just delete the blockchain and see how that goes.

Comment: If you're running it from a terminal, just add " --db-salvage" at the end of the command, but it sounds you're not running it that way. If you're letting it be started by the GUI wallet automatically, there's a text widget in the settings page where you can add custom daemon options: that's where you'd add --db-salvage. If you're running the daremon manually by clicking on an icon, then I don't know how to, but right click on the icon and see if there's a menu allowing you to do that.

Comment: OK, so the --db-salvage thing didn't work for me. So I deleted a file data.mdb found in the ~/.bitmonero area. Looks like the blockchain is re-syncing. I think this was the solution, but I'll be back in about 3 days to report once it's done syncing.

Comment: PS. Forgot to come back to update, but yes, this did fix my issue.

Answer (score -1):

You need to rebuild the database using -reindex to go back to unpruned mode.  This will redownload the entire blockchain.

Do you want to rebuild the block database now?

Comment: "using -reindex to go back to unpruned mode", wrong, there's no such option.